# Cannot send ACRA log files to cloudant

Tags: android, acra, cloudant

I am trying to send my crash log to cloudant using ACRA from many days but I always gets some sort of error in the logcat no matter what I try.
Below is the code from MyApplication :-

```
package com.greenday.lyrics;

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

import android.app.Application;

@ReportsCrashes(
    formKey="",
            formUri = "https://vishal007.cloudant.com/acra-greenday/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
                    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "thallyindshareaseriblyst", // optional
                    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "FYS5kV5cL5nR4IHFUHWRdO3j", // optional
                            reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
                            httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
                                    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
            ReportField.APPLICATION_LOG
                             },
            mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
            forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, // optional, default false
            resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text,
            applicationLogFile = "/data/data/com.greenday.lyrics/files/log/extra.log"
    )
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);

}
}
```

Below is the logcat I am getting:

```
01-22 00:54:33.909: I/ACRA(22547): Sending file 1390331334000-approved.stacktrace
01-22 00:54:33.959: D/ACRA(22547): Connect to https://vishal007.cloudant.com/acra-    greenday/_design/acra-storage/_update/report
01-22 00:54:34.079: D/ACRA(22547): Sending request to     https://vishal007.cloudant.com/acra-greenday/_design/acra-storage/_update/report/4f7c6c82-    6e05-43d8-9b57-5549600d57f2
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547): Failed to send crash report for 1390331334000-    approved.stacktrace
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547): org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while     sending JSON report via Http PUT
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  at     org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:228)
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  at     org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  at     org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Host returned error     code 404
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  at     org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:173)
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  at     org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
01-22 00:54:35.330: E/ACRA(22547):  ... 3 more
01-22 00:54:35.330: D/ACRA(22547): #checkAndSendReports - finish
01-22 00:54:35.370: D/ACRA(22547): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
01-22 00:54:35.370: E/ACRA(22547): com.greenday.lyrics fatal error : Unable to find     explicit activity class {com.greenday.lyrics/com.greenday.nimrod.Prosthetichead}; have you         declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But When I tried with

```
formUri = "https://vishal007.cloudant.com/acra-greenday/"
```

instead of

```
formUri = "https://vishal007.cloudant.com/acra-greenday/_design/acra-    storage/_update/report"
```

I was getting lots of documents in my acra-greenday database. At least I was getting anything, but I was unable to understand it. Plus, I was not able to attach my custom log.
But this formUri is not working no matter what.

Comment: I think I figured it out,  when I use formUri = "https://vishal007.cloudant.com/acra-greenday/"  with method as PUT, I get only one file and when I pressed on "Edit doc" on that file (by mistake I did) I got all my data which I mentioned in custom report with the custom log also. I think this solves my problem. And logcat also shows no error in sending the log.

Comment: remove your username and password man !

Comment: @Vishal: I know its more than two and half years now, but if at all you reading this,can you please tell when you say _"I pressed on Edit doc`_ where did you get this Edit doc option?

Comment: @Atul sry I don't remember. I left this stuff long time ago, so you're on your own ):